# Parametrize a Presto SQL statement where condition, to select all rows between a start and end date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large SQL statement which has a number of smaller SQL statements bound by a WITH statement and all with the same date criteria. My preference is to update the upper and lower bounds in one place and all where conditions are set.

My start and end dates:

```
param AS (                       
                        TIMESTAMP '2024-03-23 23:59:50' AS start_date,
                        TIMESTAMP '2024-03-23 23:59:59' AS end_date  
),
```

My Where condition:

```
 (FROM_UNIXTIME(hpd_help_desk.submit_date, 'UTC') BETWEEN (SELECT start_date from param) and (SELECT end_date from param))
```

This is not returning dates within the specific range. In Postgres SQL should I be using a different function or methodology?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Without an example of the query structure, there's not much specific guidance the SO community can provide. I strongly suggest eliminating the subqueries that retrieve `start_date` and `end_date` from `param` and instead `CROSS JOIN param` and use `BETWEEN param.start_date AND param.end_date` in each "smaller SQL statement." Even if this doesn't improve performance, it will make the code significantly more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using the `NOW` and `INTERVAL` functions. The INTERVAL and NOW functions can be amended to achieve the desired start and end dates.

```
   param AS (
                SELECT  
                        NOW() - INTERVAL '7' DAY   AS start_date,  
                        NOW() AS end_date   
    ),
```

Implemented in the Where condition via:

```
(FROM_UNIXTIME(hpd_help_desk.submit_date, 'UTC') BETWEEN (SELECT start_date from param) and (SELECT end_date from param))
```

Comment: Consider changing `start_date` and `end_date` to names more aligned with their type (in the context you've provided, it's obvious that these are timestamps, not dates). Is the intent to check for inclusion over the closed period, `start_date <= submit_date <= end_date`, or should it be a half-open period? The use of `BETWEEN` with timestamps is often indicative of a logic error. Dates are discrete, whereas timestamps are conceptually continuous.

Comment: From your answer to your own question, it appears that the title and description in the original post inadequately expressed the intended subject problem.